# Python Tiger Hash Values are Wrong

Tags: python, hash, cryptography

I am using https://github.com/browning/tiger-hash-python/

The hash from tiger.hash is wrong, leading to the base32 encoded string being wrong.

The hash as stated for an empty file/string is:

```
8B630E030AD09E5D0E90FB246A3A75DBB6256C3EE7B8635A
```

The hash I get when doing this is

```
24F0130C63AC933216166E76B1BB925FF373DE2D49584E7A
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have since tried a different python tiger hash module from the Python Package Index located here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tiger

It gives the following hash instead of being the same as the above i get:

```
3293AC630C13F0245F92BBB1766E16167A4E58492DDE73F3
```

So i do not know why this is happening still and why two modules which should give the same hash at the least are separate.

It happens on both Windows and Linux, could it be some environment variable specific to my computer perhaps? Something that is set at a hardware level so its the same as Windows and Linux?

Edit:

The base32 part of this question is for later, but i can't get the hashes to match up right, I'm trying o make a Python based Direct Connect client, and I'm working on hashing files. However the hash from tiger is wrong compared to other Direct Connect clients like DC++, they use base32 to encode it into a TTH(Tiger Tree Hash)

Wikipedia says the last hash i gave is correct: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_%28cryptography%29#Examples

And the Tiger outline page says so as well: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~biham/Reports/Tiger/test-vectors-nessie-format.dat

So the second module is doing it right, now could either of you figure out why the TTH i calculate using these functions doesn't come out as:

```
LWPNACQDBZRYXW3VHJVCJ64QBZNGHOHHHZWCLNQ
```

As that is the correct TTH hash for an empty file/string, all Direct Connnect clients like DC++, AirDC++ and others get the same hash but mine doesn't.

```
def strdivide(list,length):
    result = []
    # Calculate how many blocks there are, using the condition: i*length = len(list).
    # The additional maths operations are to deal with the last block which might have a smaller size
    for i in range(0,int(math.ceil(float(len(list))/length))):
        result.append(list[i*length:(i+1)*length])
    return result
def dchash(data):
    result = tiger.hash(data) # From the aformentioned tiger-hash-python script, 48-char hex digest
    result = "".join([ "".join(strdivide(result[i:i+16],2)[::-1]) for i in range(0,48,16) ]) # Representation Transform
    bits = "".join([chr(int(c,16)) for c in strdivide(result,2)]) # Converting every 2 hex characters into 1 normal
    result = base64.b32encode(bits) # Result will be 40 characters
    return result[:-1] # Leaving behind the trailing '='
```

Comment: Your second hash seems to match the expected value linked [on this page](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~biham/Reports/Tiger/). From where did you get the `8B630E03...` value?

Comment: Does look more like hexadecimals to me, not base32...

Comment: One common problem with tiger is that it outputs three 64 bit words. Some implementations encode those words using big-endian, others use little-endian. Your second and third string differ in endianness, no idea about the first string.

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing tiger and tiger-tree-hash (TTH). TTH is a tree hash using tiger as primitive. It's not just tiger with different encoding. The tree hash part is essential for file sharing since it enables verification of individual pieces instead of having to wait until the whole file has been downloaded.